# Where do I find the .net assemblies required for developing a SaaS website using ADFS?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, wif, adfs

Microsoft's own documentation does not seem to be very forthcoming about what I need to do to write software that can validate a user against Active Directory Federation Services (aka single sign on with AD).

Apparently, WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) is part of .NET 4.5, which I will be developing against. I am on a Windows 7 machine with VS2013. When trying to write a web page that authenticates a user belonging to a foreign Active Directory, which assembly do I need to reference, and what is the proper way to acquire it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core WIF is implemented in `System.IdentityModel.dll`.

You don't have to "acquire it", it is a part of .NET 4.5 so you just open up the reference tab, switch to system libraries and select the `System.IdentityModel` from there.

You will also probably need `System.IdentityModel.Services` to have an access to WIF's web infrastructure, namely `SessionAuthenticationModule` and `WSFederationAuthenticationModule`.